# Multiple connections to SQL Server per each web request

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, wcf, database-connection, webrequest

I'm working on a web application which it's sections are in separated projects, as a module, and these modules contain WCF services which call each other in some cases.

The question is that if each module has own connection to the database does it affect on performance or I should find a way to share the connection per each web request.

Imaging that in some scenarios four or five modules are involved, it means that each request would create more than five connection that immediately would be closed after execution.

Comment: Connections are pooled and opening/closing a lot of them is not a problem.

Comment: and I'm not sure if you would be able to share connections between WCF service calls.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practice is using connection pool.
think about what will happen if two modules going to participate in a transaction.
if you use separate connections in one transaction you will end up with distributed transaction that of course will suffer the performance.